# Не работает формула SUMIFS() вместе с IMPORTRANGE()

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Задача: есть 2 документа, необходимо суммировать сумму ячеек в одном документе при соответствии данных следующим значениям: 1) дата; 2) тип товара, и вывести значение суммы в ячейку в другом документе.

В формуле я пишу следующее:

```
=sumifs(importrange("1_zEtFp5vEQyMhnM2ryfVIXlSI9WNABfnbG46NOQb-cA"; "Январь!D:D"); importrange("1_zEtFp5vEQyMhnM2ryfVIXlSI9WNABfnbG46NOQb-cA"; "Январь!A:A"); "=21.01.2015"; importrange("1_zEtFp5vEQyMhnM2ryfVIXlSI9WNABfnbG46NOQb-cA"; "Январь!C:C"); "=Дизель")
```

Однако программа пишет в ячейке `#N/A`, а при наведении показывает

> Ошибка:  В качестве аргумента необходимо
>   указать диапазон ячеек.

Answer (score 1):

## Комментарий

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы передаете в формулу, которая ожидает массив, неизвестное содержимое. Содержимое неизвестно, потому что оно еще не возвращено. Да, и условия записаны неверно.

## Дано

К сожалению, вы не привели пример, поэтому будет мой вариант. Пусть дана Таблица с `id = 17enVVxq5roVdusG8zOnK03Dfyiquk2RIVmAuVLkHexM` с листом `"Данные"`

```
+---+------------+-----+--------+
|   |     A      |  B  |   C    |
+---+------------+-----+--------+
| 1 | 01.01.2015 | 532 | ДИЗЕЛЬ |
| 2 | 02.01.2015 | 434 | БЕНЗИН |
| 3 | 01.01.2015 | 477 | ДИЗЕЛЬ |
| 4 | 04.01.2015 | 356 | БЕНЗИН |
| 5 | 05.01.2015 | 331 | ДИЗЕЛЬ |
+---+------------+-----+--------+
```

Необходимо во второй Таблице получить сумму всех `B`, где `A = "1/1/2015"` и `C = "ДИЗЕЛЬ"`.

## Решение

### Вариант 1

Если решать по предложенному варианту, то сперва необходимо получить данные во вторую Таблицу (формула прописана в ячейке `B1` второй Таблицы)

```
=IMPORTRANGE("17enVVxq5roVdusG8zOnK03Dfyiquk2RIVmAuVLkHexM"; "Данные!A1:C20")
```

И только после этого делать расчет

```
=SUMIFS(C:C;B:B;"1/1/2015";D:D;"ДИЗЕЛЬ")
```

### Вариант 2

Для любителей "сочных" решений со вложенными вариантами, вероятнее всего, подойдет решение через `QUERY()`

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("17enVVxq5roVdusG8zOnK03Dfyiquk2RIVmAuVLkHexM"; "Данные!A:C");"select sum(Col2) where Col1 = date '2015-01-01' and Col3 = 'ДИЗЕЛЬ' label sum(Col2) 'СУММА'")
```

Этот способ вернет две строки: заголовок и результат.

## Материалы

- [Таблица с примерами (необходимо сделать копию)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17enVVxq5roVdusG8zOnK03Dfyiquk2RIVmAuVLkHexM/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)